# How can I Loop through data that is stored in my sharedpreference with a key in - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

This is the function that helps me get the data from my shared preference storage:

```
 var user;
 var userData;
 var anchors; 
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getUserAnchor();
    super.initState();
  }

_getUserAnchor() async{
  SharedPreferences localStorage  = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var userJson = localStorage.getString('loginRes');
     user = json.decode(userJson);  
     anchors = user['Anchors'];
     print(anchors);
    
     setState(() {
        userData = anchors;
     });
}
```

This is the widget that is  supposed to display the data:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dashboard'),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 10),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.card_membership,
                    size: 35, color: Colors.orange[400]),
                Text(
                  'Assigned Anchors',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange[400], fontSize: 25),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.notifications_none, size: 35, color: Colors.white)
              ],
            ),
            Column(
                children: persons.map((p) {
              return personDetailCard(p); //this is where I want to display the data
            }).toList())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is how the json array is looking in the shared preferences after successful login:

```
{
 "Anchors": [
    {
      "Oid": 11,
      "Name": "MAIZE ASSOCIATION OF NIGERIA",
      "Acronym": "MAAN",
      "DistributionCentres": [
        {
          "Oid": 11,
          "Name": "Logo Centre (Zone A)",
          "Address": "Private Warehouse, Ugba, Logo LGA"
        },
        {
          "Oid": 12,
          "Name": "Makurdi Centre (Zone B)",
          "Address": "Ministry of Agric, Makurdi "
        },
        {
          "Oid": 13,
          "Name": "Oturkpo Centre (Zone C)",
          "Address": "Private Warehouse, Oturkpo"
        },
        {
          "Oid": 15,
          "Name": "Borno MAAN centre",
          "Address": "Bolori Store, Flavour Mill, Behind Vita Foam, Maiduguri"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Oid": 2,
      "Name": "MAIZE GROWERS, PROCESSORS AND MARKETERS ASSOCIATION OF NIGERIA",
      "Acronym": "MAGPAMAN",
      "DistributionCentres": [
        {
          "Oid": 2,
          "Name": "Guma Centre",
          "Address": "P 32, 2nd Avenue Federal Housing Estate, N/Bank, Makurdi"
        },
        {
          "Oid": 3,
          "Name": "Logo Centre",
          "Address": "Terhemen Akema Storage Facility, Ugba, Logo LGA"
        },
        {
          "Oid": 5,
          "Name": "Oturkpo Centre",
          "Address": "Grain Store, Lower Benue Okele Project, Otukpo"
        },
        {
          "Oid": 6,
          "Name": "Gboko Centre",
          "Address": "K3 New Road, Opposite former coca cola plant. Solar Schools Street, Gboko"
        },
        {
          "Oid": 7,
          "Name": "Gwer East Centre",
          "Address": "Ahua Shardye's Warehouse, Behind Sylkan Filling Station, Ikpayongo , G/East LGA"
        },
        {
          "Oid": 8,
          "Name": "Kwande Centre",
          "Address": "KM 3, Adagi Road, Adikpo"
        },
        {
          "Oid": 9,
          "Name": "Ohimini Centre",
          "Address": "Ajoga Oglewu, Ohimini"
        },
        {
          "Oid": 10,
          "Name": "Oju Centre",
          "Address": "Behind Town Hall, Ohuhu owo, Oju LGA"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

so I want to display the name, the acronym, and count DistributionCentres but I don't know how to go about it. can somebody help me? I am using shared preferences because there are numbers anchors assigned to a logged-in user. Initially, I was able to do this by hard-coding an array within the file but I couldn't achieve the same with shared preference. please can someone help me? Please. If it works so I will get rid of the hard-coded Person Array object.

Here's the overall page view below:

```
import 'package:erg_app/StockPage.dart';
import 'package:erg_app/models/users_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:erg_app/Widgets/nav-drawer.dart';
import 'package:erg_app/models/eopmodel.dart';
import 'package:erg_app/StartScan.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: EopPage(),
    ));

class EopPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<EopPage> {
  List<Person> persons = [
    Person(
        name: 'RIFAN',
        profileImg: 'assets/images/user.png',
        allocated_farmers: "300",
        validated_farmers: "345",
        non_validated_farmers: "120",
        daily_inventory_status: "Completed",
        distribution_centers: "100"),
    Person(
        name: 'MAAN',
        profileImg: 'assets/images/user.png',
        allocated_farmers: "230",
        validated_farmers: "195",
        non_validated_farmers: "110",
        daily_inventory_status: "Incompleted",
        distribution_centers: "70"),
    Person(
        name: 'COPMAN',
        profileImg: 'assets/images/user.png',
        allocated_farmers: "560",
        validated_farmers: "45",
        non_validated_farmers: "780",
        daily_inventory_status: "Completed",
        distribution_centers: "40"),
  ];

  Widget personDetailCard(Person) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

      ////////////// 1st card///////////

      child: Card(
        elevation: 4.0,
        color: Colors.grey[100],
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 20, bottom: 10),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 20, bottom: 10),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 50.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            image: new DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: AssetImage(Person.profileImg)))),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    Person.name,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                      fontSize: 20,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(width: 10),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'Allocated Farmers:',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70, top: 12),
                    child: Text(
                      Person.allocated_farmers,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'Validated Farmers:',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70, top: 12),
                    child: Text(
                      Person.validated_farmers,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'Non Validated Farmers:',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 12),
                    child: Text(
                      Person.non_validated_farmers,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'Distribution Centers:',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, top: 12),
                    child: Text(
                      Person.distribution_centers,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'Daily Inventory Status:',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, top: 12),
                    child: Text(
                      Person.daily_inventory_status,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Person.daily_inventory_status == 'Completed'
                            ? Colors.green
                            : Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  /////////// Buttons /////////////

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Person.daily_inventory_status == 'Completed'
                        ? FlatButton(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 8, bottom: 8, left: 10, right: 10),
                              child: Text(
                                'Validate Farmer',
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.green,
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => StartScanPage()));
                              // Edit()was here
                            },
                          )
                        : FlatButton(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 8, bottom: 8, left: 10, right: 8),
                              child: Text(
                                'Take Inventory',
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => StockPage()));
                            },
                          ),
                  ),

                  /////////// End of Buttons /////////////
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  
 var user;
 var userData;
 var anchors; 
  @override
  void initState() {
    _getUserAnchor();
    super.initState();
  }

_getUserAnchor() async{
  SharedPreferences localStorage  = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var userJson = localStorage.getString('loginRes');
     user = json.decode(userJson);  
     anchors = user['Anchors'];
     print(anchors);
    
     setState(() {
        userData = anchors;
     });
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dashboard'),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 10),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.card_membership,
                    size: 35, color: Colors.orange[400]),
                Text(
                  'Assigned Anchors',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange[400], fontSize: 25),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.notifications_none, size: 35, color: Colors.white)
              ],
            ),
            Column(
                children: persons.map((p) {
              return personDetailCard(p);
            }).toList())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for you to achieve your scenario..

```
   var user;
   var userData;
   List anchors = [];

   _getUserAnchor() async{
    SharedPreferences localStorage  = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    user = userJson;  
    setState(() {
      anchors = user['Anchors'];       
    });
    print(anchors);
    setState(() {
     userData = anchors;
    });
   }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('test'),),
    body: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: anchors.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i){
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(anchors[i]['Name']),
                Text(anchors[i]['Oid'].toString()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      })
    ],
   ),
 );
}
```

Here I didn't get data from shared preferences i have equal your json to userJson, U can use your same steps get the data from shared preferences and follow up, So you can build list of card's.. hope this will help you...

Comment: Il send it to you within today

Comment: oh oh ok bro thank you very much. while I await the file you'll send let me try it out. I really appreciate.

Comment: Thank you very very much @s.am.i

Comment: Let me know if it work's..And please accept that as the answer

Comment: Ok, it worked very well. I will accept that.  But one more thing, please. if I parse an **Oid**  of each of the anchors to a detailed screen and that **Oid** has another key and values just like the anchors please how can I loop through that do you have any suggestion, sir. I tried it and the **Oid** pulled all the values belonging to it to the detailed screen quite ok even with the nested once but how to loop through the nested values in the detailed screen is the problem. the nested values are **DistributionCentres** in the array I provided earlier. please sir do you have any clue?

Comment: Hi, i am sorry i didn't get the question well, can you please explain step by step what you want to do??

Comment: ok please here is the details explanation sir : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559731/how-can-i-iterate-over-an-array-of-objects-which-belong-to-a-key-value-flutter

Comment: All I want to do is just advance what is working so far. after using the solution u provided to allow me loop throught anchors, I made the link which says view details because I can't display everything in a single view. so when you on the details link it should carry the id of the anchor to a details screen. in that screen I can display the name, the oid but the distributioncenters is another arrary so how to loop through it again is the problem.

Comment: I have posted and answer for that question check that and see, if you want more i'l explain more..

Comment: In your scenario is it ok to get whole json in detailed screen too??

Comment: ok saw it actually I just want to get the json for just that single anchor not the whole anchor sir

Comment: You can send the touched index by getting from list view index and in detail screen you can use one for loop and loop il update the answer