# looping through json objects in json object

Tags: c#, json, flutter, model-view-controller

I have been working in flutter for the project that sends http.post request to a c# api. The request sent is like this (in json format)

```
{
  "name": "Sarbjit Singh",
  "age": 23,
  "dob": "1/1/2020",
  "cart": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "keyboard",
      "quantity": 3,
      "price": 123.45
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "keyboard",
      "quantity": 3,
      "price": 123.45
    },
    "4": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "keyboard",
      "quantity": 3,
      "price": 123.45
    }
  }
}
```

This structure needs to be as it is. No modifications can be made in this structure.

I receive the request in a controller like this

```
 public class ServiceOrder
    {
        public string lat;
        public string lng;
        public string address;
        public double amount;
        public string username;
        public Cart cart;
    }

    public class CartItem
    {
        public int id;
        public string title;
        public int quantity;
        public double price;
    }

    public class Cart
    {
        public int id;
        public string title;
        public int quantity;
        public double price;
    }

    [RoutePrefix("services")]
    public class ServiceOrderController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("orders/add")]
        public object AddOrder([FromBody] ServiceOrder order)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString);
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into serviceorders (orderid, lat, lng, address, username, cartvalue, dateordered, status) values ((select coalesce(max(orderid),0)+1 from serviceorders),@lat, @lng, @address, @username, @cartvalue, @dateordered, 1); select top 1 orderid, ordernumber from serviceorders where username=@username order by orderid desc;", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lat", order.lat);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lng", order.lng);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", order.address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", order.username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cartvalue", order.amount);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateordered", Common.Utils.IndianTime());
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string ordernumber = string.Empty;
            long orderid = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ordernumber = dr["ordernumder"].ToString();
                orderid = Convert.ToInt64(dr["orderid"].ToString());
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ordernumber))
                return new { error = true, message = "Unable to add your order. Try later" };
            else
                return new { error = false, message = "Order placed successfully", orderN = ordernumber };
        }
```

This works well but I am unable to iterate through cart of the json object using c#:
This part:

```
"cart": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "keyboard",
      "quantity": 3,
      "price": 123.45
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "keyboard",
      "quantity": 3,
      "price": 123.45
    },
    "4": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "keyboard",
      "quantity": 3,
      "price": 123.45
    }
  }
```

Please suggest an efficient way to iterate over it.

Update:

This is how a http post request is built. Any modification is highly welcomed.

```
 Future placeOrder(lat, lng, address, amount, cart) async {
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String mobile = _prefs.getString('mobile');

    String target =
        '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('api_base_url')}users';
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'lat': lat,
      'lng': lng,
      'address': address,
      'amount': amount,
      'username': mobile,
      'cart': jsonEncode(cart.toMap())
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried to serialize the object and iterate through it that way?

Comment: What exactly does not iterate? Is it this: `while (dr.Read())` ? Your query only selects top 1.

Comment: if you notice there is a property in ServiceOrder class as  public Cart cart; I am unable to iterate through it.

Comment: Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559731/how-can-i-iterate-over-an-array-of-objects-which-belong-to-a-key-value-flutter).

Comment: Cart is not a collection, so that would by why. Is `Cart` supposed to have a property which is a list of `CartItem`?

Comment: I dont know exactly if the above classes meet the criteria of json provided. It is sure that there is no collection at all. I can not change the way json is structured.

Comment: The problem with the json is that the cart items are not an array, they are just a series of objects. This is poor design and it is too bad you are forced to deal with it. You'll probably have to parse it as a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` and manually map the nodes to your class structure (which also must change to accomodate multiple cart items).

Comment: I have added an update on how the json is built. Please suggest a better way

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can parse the json to `CartItem`s. I assume that is the part you are stuck on and will leave the rest of your solution up to you. This is way harder than you should have to work with JSON. Whoever designed the API is unfamiliar with JSON etiquette.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jobj_cart = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(cartJson);

// This is Service Order stuff I guess, does not match your class though:
string name = (string)jobj_cart["name"];
string age = (string)jobj_cart["age"];
string dob = (string)jobj_cart["dob"];

// Get the cart data
var cart = jobj_cart["cart"];

//Create a list of cart items that will collect them as we loop
List<CartItem> cartItems = new List<CartItem>();

//loop over objects in the cart, pluck out the values, add a new CartItem to the list
foreach (JProperty element in cart)
{
    var id = element.Value["id"].Value<int>();
    var title = element.Value["title"].Value<string>();
    var quantity = element.Value["quantity"].Value<int>();
    var price = element.Value["price"].Value<double>(); // <-- side note, money should be represented by Decimal, not Double

    cartItems.Add(new CartItem {id = id, title = title,  quantity = quantity, price = price});      
}
```

Comment: jsonCart is actually json iteself, not a string. JObject.Parse needs a string. Can I do JObject.Parse(jsonCart.ToString()) to convert it into and continue??

Comment: Does your controller still work if you change its signature from `[FromBody] ServiceOrder order` to `[FromBody] string order` ? If it does you should be able to parse `order` in the way I described above.

Comment: "ExceptionMessage": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: s",